# Perl snippet keep verifying server cert despite effort asking it not to

Tags: perl

I got the the following code that I thought it will not verify server cert, but it still does:

```
500 Can't connect to 10.0.0.9:443 (certificate verify failed)
```

Not sure why.  Here is the code snippet:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'https://10.0.0.9/test1234');
$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 );
my $res = $ua->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content;
}
else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was following the suggestion from [link](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/now-you-need-lwpprotocolhttps.html).

Turned out the "verify_hostnames" should be "verify_hostname".

Comment: Apart from that depending on the installed version of LWP `verify_hostname ` only cares about verifying the hostname against the name in the certificate and is not disabling the validation of the trust chain. You'll find the latter behavior in stock LWP but almost all Linux distributions have it patched because of [CVE-2014-3230](https://github.com/libwww-perl/lwp-protocol-https/pull/14). Anyway, it is **bad to just disable validation**, use **SSL_fingerprint** from IO::Socket::SSL instead to set the expected certificate to make it secure.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for the additional information!